# Counting possible ways to select two disjoint subsets A and B of [n]?

Tags: combinatorics

The question I'm having trouble with is:

Let $n$ be a positive integer and define $[n]$ to be the set of the first $n$ positive integers. That is, $[n] = \{1,2,3,...,n\}.$ We want to select two disjoint subsets $A, B$ of $[n]$.

In how many ways can we do this?

Answer (score 3):

Write all the elements of $[n]$ in increasing order:

$$1\ \ 2 \ \ 3 \ \ ... \ \ n$$

We can create a bijection between this string of numbers and a number in base $3$:

$$\underbrace{0...1...2}_{n}$$

Where $0$ means that the element $i\notin A \cup B$ , $1$ means $i\in A $ and   $2$ means $i\in B $. Clearly with $A\cap B=\varnothing$ . If we consider $A$ and $B$ distinguishable ($A={1} \ \ B={2}$ is different from $A={2} \ \ B={1}$), then the answer is simply:

$$3^n$$

The number of ternary numbers of $n$ ciphers. Viceversa if the set are not distinguishable, we must divide this number for $2!=2$ , subtracting clearly the only case that doesn't have permutations($A=B=\varnothing$):

$$\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

Then we must add the empty sets case we subtracted before and we'll have:

$$\frac{3^n+1}{2}$$

**An alternative solution**

Let'call $X_n$ the number of ways searched if $|[n]|=n$. If we have $X_{n-1}$ ways , we have 3 options for the $n$-th element: add it to the first subset, to the second or not adding it. Again an exception is $A=B=\varnothing$, because here the $2$ first options are equivalent for simmetry, this means that:

$$X_n=3X_{n-1}-1$$

This is called **mixed progression** and in general:

$$X_n=aX_{n-1}+b \Rightarrow  X_n=a^n X_0+b\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$

In our case $X_0=1$ (if $[n]=\varnothing$ then clearly $A=B=\varnothing$) so we'll have:

$$X_n=3^n-\frac{3^n-1}{2} \Rightarrow X_n=\frac{3^n+1}{2}$$

:)

Comment: In your final line, you should have $\frac{3^n + 1}{2}$.  Consider the set $S = \{1\}$.  If the sets are not labeled, there are two possible disjoint pairs:  either one set is $S$ and the other is the $\emptyset$ or both sets are the $\emptyset$.  The reason for this is that we have counted every pair of subsets twice when we label them except the pair consisting of empty sets, which we have only counted once.  Since we still want to count it once when the subsets are not labeled, we must first add $1$ before dividing by $2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you are right I forgot to add again the empty set, thank you

Comment: Simple and clear. +1